# How can i send my System.out.println(); as an email

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot

I've got a program which print output on console, this program read the content inside a excel file, and print everything inside the excel spreadsheet on console. i can already send normal text through my email class, but i'm trying to send the output of the excel file on console through email, here is my code with some description:

```
public class Sendexcelcontent {

private static final String NAME = "C:\\Users\\..........\\excelfile.xlsx";

public static void excelfilereader() {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
        while (sheets.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sh = sheets.next();
            System.out.println("Sheet name is " + sh.getSheetName());
            System.out.println("---------");
            processLines(dataFormatter, sh);
        }
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private static void processLines(DataFormatter dataFormatter, Sheet sh) {
        boolean printLine = false;
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sh.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = iterator.next();
            
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String text = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        }
    }
    
    private static void printRow(DataFormatter dataFormatter, Row row) {
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
public static void sendemail() {
//authentication info
final String username = "...";
final String password = "...";
String fromEmail = "...";
String toEmail = "...";

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "...");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "...");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
    }
});
//Start our mail message
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
try {
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    msg.setSubject("Subject Line");
    msg.setText("NORMAL TEXT MESSAGE");
    
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Message sent");
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: These are total two main methods which means two programs. First you have to create a one simple program and make sending email function in a separate function which accepts excel data. Then once you read all the excel data construct those data into a array and pass to email function. Then create the email body as you want and set to the message. Please read multiple times which I explained here and please get back to me if you need further help on this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried doing this, but i don't know how to procced:

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried doing updating my code, but i don't really know how to continue from there.

Comment: if I give you a some steps to code without giving  the exact solution, will it help for you? will you be able to construct your code according to that

Comment: Yeah, please try.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `System.out` to point to a `StringWriter`.

This way, you can get the output as String and write that in the email:

```java
StringWriter emailWriter=new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(emailWriter);
System.setOut(pw);
ReadInvoices.main(new String[0]);
String text=emailWriter.toString();
//...
msg.setText(text);
```